# Object user is null after login Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

After login in symfony i see empty object user

[image]

The entity looks correct

There are no problems with the database:

[image]

Someone can help ?

Comment: Where is the user coming from? How is it retrieved?  Is there a Symfony 'firewall', requiring a user to be logged in?

Comment: I solved this problem. Instead of pulling user $ this-> getUser, I created a new user(). And it's all wrong